# What does "in the pocket" mean?

Tags: avatar-the-way-of-water

On a ship in *Avatar The Way of Water* (2022), the captain Scoresby is trying to aim a harpoon at a
mother Tulkun while commanding his sailors:

> Scoresby: Ten meters. Get me in there. Put me **in the pocket**. Now steady,
> steady. Stay with her.

What does "in the pocket" mean ?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is a billiards pocket

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if this was lifted straight out of _Moby Dick_!

Comment: This question would have been much better asked at [ell.se] or [english.se].

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe he may be using the American football version of [pocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passing_pocket).

> The passing pocket, or the pocket, is a term used in American football to describe the area in the backfield created on a passing play where the offensive line forms a wall of protection around the quarterback. This allows him adequate time to find an open receiver and to pass the ball. The offensive line will drop back slightly, creating a U-shaped protected area for the quarterback to find an open receiver and pass the ball.

Basically, he's telling them to get him in the position where he can "make his shot" while still being protected.

Comment: Quarterbacks don't say that, though, and I can't imagine any other American saying it, either.

Comment: Quite honestly, not a quarterback here. I don't know exactly how they talk. I just know that "in the pocket" is a phrase I've heard referring to that situation in football.

Comment: You're right about "*being* in the pocket" being a term in God's True Football.  It's what *announcers and fans* say, though, about QBs, and offensive linemen's competency in maintaining the pocket.  "Try and hold the pocket just a little longer next time" is what a QB might say.

Comment: This is a modern use of the idiom, which is better explained in terms of [music](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/27301), which is also a modern use of the idiom. It most likely derives from having the success of finding one's literary effort in [The Pocket magazine](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Pocket_Magazine/UAkbAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) in the mid 1800s. The movie reference means little more than "put me where I'll be successful" (and sounds cool, to boot).

Answer (score 5):

It means **within effective striking range** (not at the limit of your reach). Think of attack that don't require you to lean or fully extend.

Commonly used in boxing and similar combat sports. In the case of the movie, it means within range to use the harpoon effectively. In combat sports, being in the pocket also means you are also putting yourself in danger.

This all ties together nicely with the situation in the movie. If you have a limited amount of chances to use a weapon, you want to be as close as possible to ensure success even if it means putting yourself in danger.

- I cannot find a good source for this without violent imagery so I'm a little hesitant to cite anything for this, but a simple Google search for "in the pocket, boxing, MMA" should support the definition.

Comment: I don't see how this answer improves in the existing one.

Comment: @Valorum It doesn't - it gives what I believe to be the correct answer instead of an loosely related football term. The other answer talks about passing a ball to a friendly player and making a protected zone - neither of which relate to the movie. Of course, I might be wrong as it has been a while since I watched it, but there were no ships trying to protect them (and if there were, they could just do the harpooning themselves if they were in that position so that wouldn't make any sense).

Comment: It seems to be a boxing or MMA expression, relatively new and not one that most viewers would be aware of.

Comment: I think it's a fine addendum.

Comment: From a quick Google search, usage in Boxing seems to predate the Film

Comment: @Valorum for anyone outside the US the American football expression wouldn't necessarily be familiar

Comment: And, admittedly, it feels a bit odd for someone with a distinct Australian accent to be using *American* football terms, but that's what I was familiar with, and I figured that it might have made it out as a general phrase.

Comment: @SamDean - Yes, but it's an American film written by a Canadian (who's spent most of this life in America) made by Americans for a largely American audience starring mostly Americans talking American English and using American idioms

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Has anyone got a copy they can watch to clarify? Basically, if they have a group protecting the harpoon team out ahead of them, I believe I would be wrong. If they need to get closer to the target than the others, I believe my definition to be correct.

Comment: @Valorum less than 30% of the box office was the US ($684m/$2,320m) so I'd argue it wasn't largely for an American Audience

Answer (score -2):

It's billiards.  Line up the shot.  Put it in the pocket. All billiards terms.

Comment: You could improve your answer with some references to explain billiards to people who are unfamiliar with it.

Comment: But why would he want to be in the pocket shooting outwards? You put the ball in the pocket, you don't put yourself there